# Only the word "array" gets printed when I try to render custom block in template

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I am building a custom block in a module, like this:

```
<?php

function filterblock_block_info() {
  // Sökfilter till temperaturöversikten.
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['filterblock-temperatur'] = array(
    'info' => t('Temperatursökfilter'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function filterblock_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'filterblock-temperatur':
      $block['subject'] = t('');
      $block['content'] = filterblock_block_content();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function filterblock_block_content(){
    return drupal_get_form('temperaturfilter');
}

function temperaturfilter($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();

    $form['alla'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'textfield',
        '#title'        => t("Alla"),
        '#weight'       => 10,
        '#required'     => false,
    );
    $form['IR'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'textfield',
        '#title'        => t("IR"),
        '#weight'       => 11,
        '#required'     => false,
    );

    $form['hightemp'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'textfield',
        '#title'        => t("> +500 °C"),
        '#weight'       => 12,
        '#required'     => false,
    );
    $form['lowtemp'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'textfield',
        '#title'        => t("< -50 °C"),
        '#weight'       => 13,
        '#required'     => false,
    );

    return $form;
}
```

In my template file I have this:

```
   <?php $block = module_invoke('filterblock', 'block_view', 'filterblock-temperatur'); ?>
   <?php  if ($block['content']) {
     $output = "<div class=\"filter-block\">\n";
     $output .= "<div class=\"content\">".$block['content']."</div>\n";
     $output .= "</div>\n";
     print $output;
```

But the only thing that is rendered on the page is the word "array". I have checked with var_dump in the block module that `$block['content']` actually contains the fields from the function `temperaturfilter`. I have tried to use print render($output) in stead of just print, but with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t rendered the render array:

```
$output .= "<div class=\"content\">".render($block['content'])."</div>\n";
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! You saved me a lot of time. That worked straight away.